# Dehydration of aldol

Tags: organic-chemistry, aldol-reaction

In my book it is written that to dehydrate an aldol the product of aldol condensation is heated in an iodine environment. But what is the role of Iodine here and how does it catalyse the dehydration of the aldol?

Comment: The aldol is not the product of an aldol condensation but rather the unsaturated carbonyl compound is the result of a condensation. A condensation requires the loss of some small molecule such as water or alcohol. The iodine likely generates a catalytic amount of HI by oxidation of some alcohol in the aldol substrate. Acid catalyzed loss of water occurs to afford the aldol condensation product.